# Select from two tables with different order column

Tags: sql

I have two tables with three columns each:

- `tbl_music` (id, title, reg_time)
- `tbl_movie` (id, title, time_log)

For `sitemap.xml` I want add all item from the two tables in file order by time. The two tables are separate and time field are `reg_time` and `time_log`.

How can I join two tables and order from value on two tables?

Comment: Use [UNION ALL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180026.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following case, the result set includes the contents of both the `tbl_music` and `tbl_movie` tables

```
select * from 
( select id, title, reg_time as time from tbl_music 
  union all
  select id, title, time_log as time from tbl_movie
) results
order by time
```